# How to fix - Dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to implement ''Dropdown'' with filter(search) in AngularJS. While trying i'm not getting as 'dropdown' select menu.
The following images show before and after search in dropdown.

A text inbox like structuring is appearing while searching.

[image: before searching in dropdown]

[image: While searching]

Please help me to fix this and where i'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

My code follows here:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Select with search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
          href="node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.min.css" />
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/ui-select/dist/select.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="selectCtrl">{{1+1}}
        <ui-select ng-model="num.selected" theme='bootstrap'>

            <ui-select-match>
                {{$select.selected.name}}
            </ui-select-match>

            <ui-select-choices repeat='n in nums | filter: $select.search'>
                {{n.name}} ({{n.email}})

            </ui-select-choices>

        </ui-select>
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.select']);
        app.controller("selectCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.num = {};
            $scope.nums = [{
                    name: 'apple',
                    email: 'apple@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'alfa',
                    email: 'alfa@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'bat',
                    email: 'bat@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'cat',
                    email: 'cat@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'dog',
                    email: 'dog@gmail.com'
                },
                {
                    name: 'monkey',
                    email: 'mon@gmail.com'
                }
            ];

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use the full development version of angularjs to get more verbose error output and tell us what module name is not found. Or follow the generated link in error to the error.docs page that gives you an explanation

Comment: @charlietfl Error is  solved. Could you help to solve this dropdown.Thanks

Comment: Create a plunker demo that reproduces problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like a css error, check your css classes are actually loaded

It might be because you are missing the **rel** and **type**

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">

check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: CSS is working fine.Could you check with logical code.Thanks for ur effort

Comment: Check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nfew1kgs/3/
None of the code was changed, but I've added cdns for ui-select and bootstrap